# Grails 4.0.1 app loading pages first time takes time after restart

Tags: grails, startup

I have a medium-sized application that recently migrated from Grails 2.2.1 to Grails 4.0.1. The app startup fast, but when I visit the pages, its takes time first time, but from then on loads immediately. Is there anything that I can do to load the pages fast even the first time ? I set lazyInit = false for all the services to initialize all service on startup.

I also tried hitting the controllers on startup by implementing ApplicationRunner and loading all controllers from run method. Still no luck.

Running app as spring-boot war with embedded tomcat. Using grails 4.0.1 on java version "1.8.0_181"

Comment: Have you tried to change the webapp log level to ALL / DEBUG / VERBOSE and check what takes so much time?

Comment: Enabled java verbose log. Seems to me like loading gsp from war is where the most time spent.

Comment: Share it with us

Comment: @KiranChitturi you have anything to share? I ran over the same issue.

Answer (score -3):

because from Grails 2.x.x to Grails.3.x.x ,there are many breaking changes.
so suggestions as below:

1. try upgrade to Grails 3.x.x,if done ,then try
2. upgrade to Grails 4.x.x

Comment: No issues migrating 2.2.4 to 4.0.1. App works fine after migration. Its just the pages first time takes time.